# pgfplots: hide grid line in axis discontinuity

Tags: pgfplots, axis

When combining `axis y discontinuity=crunch` and `grid` as in the MWE below the grid line is visible in the discontinuity, cf. `(0,0) -- (0,0.2)` in the MWE. How can one avoid this without adjusting axis limits?

---

###### MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y discontinuity=crunch,
        xmin=0,
        ymin=0,
        grid,
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe result]

Comment: The easy solution is to draw a [fill=white] band acroo the page, or draw the gird outside the axis environment with clipping.  Upi would need to record all the end points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not use `extra x ticks` for anything else, then you can use them to not draw first and last grid lines like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis y discontinuity=crunch,
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
grid,
xtick={0.2,0.4,...,0.8},
extra x ticks={0,1},
extra x tick style={grid=none},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant, but it works.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}% redundant
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y discontinuity=crunch,
        xmin=0, xmax=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1,
        name=border
        ]
      \addplot[domain=0:1, red] {x};
    \end{axis}
% Note (border.south west)=(0,0)
    \path (border.north east);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\xs}{\ys}%
    \begin{scope}[even odd rule, on background layer]
      \clip (1pt,0) rectangle (\xs-1pt, \ys)
        (1pt, 0.03*\ys) rectangle (\xs-1pt, 0.11*\ys);% by eyeball
      \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid[xstep={\xs/5}, ystep={\ys/5}] (\xs, \ys);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by John's idea:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y discontinuity=crunch,
        xmin=0, xmax=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1,
        set layers,
        grid,
        ]
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis grid}
            \draw[white] (0,0) -- (0,1);
            \draw[white] (1,0) -- (1,1);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 - One of the solutions I also looked at. Your white lines have the same width as default grid lines, so it is safer to make them thick, so there are no viewer artefacts. -and by using `axis description cs:` it will be independent of `xmin` and `xmax` like this: `\draw[white, thick] (axis description cs:0,0) -- (axis description cs:0,1) (axis description cs:1,0) -- (axis description cs:1,1);`

Comment: Ok - maybe `thick` is not optimal, as it cuts into the start of the horizontal grid lines. -so then the white lines should not be drawn all the way, but only up to below the first horizontal grid line.